# Why State won't Change When I try to dispatch in getServerSideProps? Redux-Next-Wrapper

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, next.js, redux-toolkit

When I Try to dispatch in getServerSideProps the Redux Store won't change

When i Console.log the store After Dispatch I see the changes in console but when the page load the Store is empty array..

Why Changes won't effect?

createSlice

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { Store } from "../../types/type";

const { actions, reducer } = createSlice({
  name: "dashboard",
  initialState: { users: [], roles: [], ads: [], category: [] },
  reducers: {
    SET_ROLES: (store, { payload }) => {
      store.roles = payload;
      return store;
    },
    SET_USERS: (store, { payload }) => {
      store.users = payload;
      return store;
    },
    SET_ADS: (store, { payload }) => {
      store.ads = payload;
      return store;
    },
    SET_CATEGORY: (store, { payload }) => {
      store.category = payload;
      return store;
    },
  },
});

// Selector

export const selectDashboard = (store: Store) => store.entities.dashboard;

export const { SET_ROLES, SET_ADS, SET_USERS, SET_CATEGORY } = actions;
export default reducer;
```

Page

```js
export const getServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(
  (store) => async (context) => {
    const { data: ads } = await axios.get(endPoint);
    const { data: users } = await axios.get(endPoint);
    const { data: roles } = await axios.get(endPoint);
    const { data: categories } = await axios.get(endPoint);
    console.log("Before DISPATCH", store.getState());
    store.dispatch(SET_USERS(users));
    store.dispatch(SET_ADS(ads));
    store.dispatch(SET_CATEGORY(categories));
    store.dispatch(SET_ROLES(roles));
    console.log("After DISPATCH", store.getState()); // I Can See The Changes In Console
    return {
      props: {},
    };
  }
);
```

Comment: Please check the terminal (command window), not the browser console. All `consoel.log` inside `getServerSideProps` will print in the terminal only.

Comment: @AhammedKM i Checked there and I Saw the changes but when the page load the store is empty

Comment: The state set in the server will get cleared when dehydrations happen. You need to update server state with client state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state set in the server will get cleared when dehydrations happen. You need to update server state with client state.

```
const reducer = (
  state: ReturnType<typeof combinedReducer> | undefined,
  action: AnyAction
) => {
  if (action.type === HYDRATE) {
    const nextState = {
      ...state, // use previous state
      ...action.payload, // apply delta from hydration
    };
    return nextState;
  } else {
    return combinedReducer(state, action);
  }
};



export const store = configureStore({
  reducer,
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
  ....
```